# How can i install Pyqt4 on win 8?

Tags: pyqt4

I'm seeking to learn Python Gui with pyqt, and I have installed the v5 of it, but when i tried to learn it I've found that most of the tutorials about v4 only, So i tried to get V4 installed , but the problem is that it needs to be manually installed with  no binary(exe) installation .

So would someone help me please with installing v4 on windows 8.1 and with latest version of python already installed?

I need the steps , or simply find me a complete v5 tutorials to download.
thank you all in advance.

Comment: python2 or python3?

Comment: download installer from https://sourceforge.net/projects/pyqt/files/PyQt4/PyQt-4.10/

Comment: when i tried to import  " QtGui " I get this error>>>Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Mahmoud/Desktop/py-learn/code_1.py", line 2, in <module>
    from PyQt4 import QtGui
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

Process finished with exit code 1